# Bootstrap container-fluid to occupy the parent

Tags: html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate bootstrap into our webapp. How do I let `container-fluid` occupy it's parent's width? The problem is it occupies more..

[here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akiwarheit/3T5Et/). I only want `container-fluid` to wrap the contents within the `main-panel` which spans 100% of the remaining width...

Comment: Please don't change your fiddles when you reference them in posts. Just create new ones. It reduces the usefulness of the information for people viewing the post at a later date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the class "row-fluid" instead of "row" solves your problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The term "Occupies more" I think it means it has fixed width in px or any unit. It should has percentage width and set margin to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="span2">This DOES NOT goes beyond the screen.</div>
```

You need to change the div class from `span12` to `span2`

Comment: I'd like to use `span12` considering that I'll be putting a table to display data.